# SMB: The account is not authorized to log in from this station

Tags: windows-10, file-sharing, smb

When I try to visit \\192.168.1.x on one of my computers I get the following error:

> \\192.168.1.x is not accessible. You might not have permission to
>   use this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to
>   find out if you have access permissions.
>
> The account is not authorized to log in from this station.

At first I thought it might be because the SMB server had [hit the limit of concurrent connections](http://www.itprotoday.com/windows-7/q-it-true-windows-7-allows-20-concurrent-connections-instead-10) but `netstat` just shows one "active connection".

[Problem: The account is not authorized to login from this station](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/cc1d74af-f739-4070-84fb-86319d103cc9/problem-the-account-is-not-authorized-to-login-from-this-station?forum=itprovistanetworking) suggests setting `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Parameters\enablesecuritysignature` to 0 but it's already 0 and I'm still getting the error.

The laptop I'm trying to connect from (Windows 10) is one I use on multiple different networks FWIW. I use it at my job and I use it at my house. I'm also able to open the SMB share from other computers on my LAN (again Windows 10) - just not this dual use laptop.

The server is running Windows 7. The username on the laptop does not exist on the server but I wouldn't expect that to make a difference - what I'd expect to happen in this scenario is that the laptop would prompt me for a username / password that the server would accept but it's not doing that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do the server and the broken client perhaps have identical hostnames (computer names)? Is the laptop connected to MS Active Directory at your job?

Comment: @grawity - the hostnames are different but the laptop is indeed connected to MS Active Directory at my job.

Comment: The SMB server is configured to trust the AD domain?  You are mounting the share volume as which user?

Comment: @Ramhound - idk how to configure the SMB server to trust the AD domain. As for the user that's mounting the share volume...  since it's not even prompting me for a username / password I guess it's trying to do the username / password of the user on the laptop. It used to prompt for auth info but now it doesn't anymore and I didn't change anything. Maybe some windows automatic update changed stuff...

Comment: When you mount a volume you are given a chance to provide a username and password in the event, of let's say a Samba share or a Windows share, where the user profile you are using is not specifically given permission and a different user must be used.  If this prompt is not being provide, then use the command prompt method, and specific the user and password instead.  How you mount a SMB share with the command prompt is well documented.

Comment: Are you logged into the laptop as a domain user when you do this? Do you get different results if you logon the Windows 10 machine with a local account instead of a domain account?